# I want to make my long reference link dynamic with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink, get

First of all, I have a link that takes 2 parameters;

**http://localhost/project/home.php?SK=2&referance=1**

?SK=2 is my first parameter and &referance=1 is my second parameter. The SK=2 parameter draws my files in the php file, and the referance=1 parameter prints the value from the get method to my registration page. What I want is to put this link in below format with htaccess

**http://localhost/project/register?referance=1**

The link I made before brings my register page, but now I want it to bring the reference code, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Htaccess code I used before;

```
RewriteRule ^register$ home.php?SK=2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You used `referance` in your example URLs, but `reference` in your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^register$ home.php?SK=2 [NC,L]
> ```

You just need to add the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag to your existing rule.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^register$ home.php?SK=2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This will now rewrite `/register` to `/home.php?SK=2` **and** `/register?referance=1` to `/home.php?SH=2&referance=1`.

Reference:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: what you said didn't work

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? What happened exactly? This rewrites the example you posted in the question. Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Temporarily add the `R` flag to the rule - what happens now?

Comment: it still didn't work. I wonder if there is a problem with my htaccess link;
`RewriteRule ^register$ home.php?SK=2 [QSA,NC,L,R]`

Comment: Include a slash prefix on the _substitution_ string: `RewriteRule ^register$ /home.php?SK=2 [QSA,NC,L,R]` - This is just temporary in order to debug it.

Comment: it worked! I edited my file on the server by mistake, now I edited my local server and it worked. thank you so much. useful link;
`RewriteRule ^register$ home.php?SK=2 [QSA,NC,L]`